# Array retornando Undefined por causa do assincronismo

Tags: javascript, node.js, assincronismo

Estou acessando a [API do Trello](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference), porém me deparei com o seguinte problema:

Acesso as informações do Trello, obtendo o id de cada fila existente, o código é o seguinte:

```
var x;  
var numberCardsByList = [];

trello.get("/1/boards/[idBoard]/lists/all", function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Quantidade de Filas: " + data.length);

    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        x = data[i];
        findNumberCards(x);
    }
});
```

Como podem ver, depois de obter o tamanho, eu percorro todas essas filas com o `for`, dentro do laço, atribuo cada fila em uma variável `x` e chamo uma função que tem como objetivo, obter o número de *cards* dessa fila. O código para obter o número de *cards* é o seguinte:

```
trello.get("/1/lists/"+x.id+"/cards", function(err, dados){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("A fila com nome: " + x.name + " tem " + dados.length + " cards");
    numberCardsByList[x.name] = dados.length;
});
```

Até ai tudo certo, porém, quando tento acessar o vetor `numberCardsByList` depois do fim da busca no trello, ele retorna undefined:

```
var x;  
var numberCardsByList = [];

trello.get("/1/boards/[idBoard]/lists/all", function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Quantidade de Filas: " + data.length);

    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        x = data[i];
        findNumberCards(x);
    }
});
console.log(numberCardsByList);
```

Estou ciente que é por causa do assincronismo, porém, não consigo solucionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens de ter esses pedidos encadeados (dentro uns dos outros) para poderes montá-los assincronamente.

Há uma [biblioteca muito boa para isso](https://github.com/caolan/async) que tem um método [`async.map`](https://github.com/caolan/async#map) que faz o que queres.

No teu caso poderias aplicar assim:

```
var async = require('async');

function findNumberCards(fila, callback) {
    trello.get("/1/lists/" + fila.id + "/cards", callback);
}

trello.get("/1/boards/[idBoard]/lists/all", function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Quantidade de Filas: " + data.length);
    async.map(data, findNumberCards, function(err, arr) {
        var numberCardsByList = {};
        arr.forEach(function(dados, i) {
            numberCardsByList[data[i].name] = dados.length;
        });
        // aqui tens o objeto numberCardsByList montado!
        console.log(numberCardsByList);
    });
});
```

Dessa maneira ele corre a função `findNumberCards` para cada elemento da array que receber.

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que sua variável global `x` está sendo sobrescrita antes de ser utilizada novamente no retorno da API para obter os cards.

A solução mais simples seria passar a variável `x.name` como parâmetro no lugar do próprio `x`, já que é o único valor que está sendo utilizado.

Outra solução é clonar a variável `x` que é passada como parâmetro, utilizando por exemplo o método [`extend`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) do jQuery ou o método [`clone`](http://underscorejs.org/#clone) do underscore.js.